# What is the best way to play sound in a piano application?

Tags: ios, audio

I'm developing a piano-like application and tried both libraries:

**AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h**

```
-(void)playSound :(NSString *)fName :(NSString *) ext{
    SystemSoundID audioEffect;
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource : fName ofType :ext];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath : path]) {
        NSURL *pathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef) pathURL, &audioEffect);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(audioEffect);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"error, file not found: %@", path);
    }
}
```

Then I would just call it with something like

```
[self playSound:@"c_sharp" :@"mp3"];
```

The problem with this approach was that when I hit the button that calls ***playSound*** method, there is a 1-2 second delay. Also, **AudioServicesPlaySystemSound** seem to play on system volume, which cannot be controlled by volume rocker if that option is disabled.

---

I also tried different approach to play sound with

**AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *fileC2 = [mainBundle pathForResource:@"c_sharp" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSData *soundC2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileC2];
    NSError *error = nil;
    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:soundC2
                                                     error:&error];
    [self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
}
```

Then to play the sound, I'd

```
- (IBAction)c_sharp_press:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.audioPlayer play];
}
```

The problem with this approach was that I can only play **one** sound at a time. If I hit the same piano key, instead of adding another similar sound, it won't do anything until the first sound is done playing. There is also a small 1/2 second delay as well.

---

My question is:

What library do I use to implement a piano keyboard so that:

1. There is no or unnoticeable delay in playing sounds.
2. The sound is controlled by the volume rocker.
3. I can play more than one sound at a time.

Comment: Implement `AudioQueue`s and your custom waveform/frequency generator function. It will work and it will work well once you get it working, but that's going to be tough.

Answer (score 1):

See the sample code for Apple's [loadPresetDemo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LoadPresetDemo/Introduction/Intro.html). This code demos how to use an `AUSampler Unit` with custom audio clips. This is the best approach for making musical instrument type apps as the `AUSampler` is optimized for responsive playback, low latency, memory preload and usage, etc. The other methods of playing audio in iOS are not well suited for playing short sounds in rapid succession.